TypeScript utility type - interface where at least one property is required, except for certain specified properties
Background
Suppose I have an interface with all optional values:
interface MyInterface
{
    property1?: string
    property2?: string
    proeprty3?: string
}

When using MyInterface as typing, I can specify that at least one of its properties is required using the following utility type:
type AtLeastOnePropRequired<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: Record<P, T[P]> }[keyof T]
type CustomRequired<T> = T & AtLeastOnePropRequired<T>

Usage example:
// At least one of `property1`, `property2`, or `property3` is required.
CustomRequired<MyInterface>

This is somewhat similar to Required, except that utility type would make all the properties mandatory, not just one.
As an aside, here's another way to implement AtLeastOnePropRequired:
type AtLeastOnePropRequired<T> = T & { [P in keyof T]: Required<Pick<T, P>> }[keyof T]


Problem
Suppose I want to extend MyInterface and add one new property that's also optional:
interface NewInterface extends MyInterface
{
    property4?: boolean
}

The wrinkle here is that I can't use CustomRequired in the same way anymore. If I were to use CustomRequired<NewInterface>, it would mean:

At least one of property1, property2, property3, or property4
is required.

What I need is a typing that means:

At least one of property1, property2, or property3 is required.
property4 is optional, but if provided, doesn't satisfy the previous
requirement.

Please see the "Conclusion" section below for usage examples of what this may look like.
I'm trying to adjust CustomRequired to handle situations like this.

Examples
Here's an example of what should not satisfy the typing requirement:
// Does not contain one of `property1`, `property2`, or `property3`.
{
    property4: false
}

Here are examples of what should satisfy the typing requirement:
// Does contain one of `property1`, `property2`, or `property3`.
{
    property1: "hello world!",
    property3: "goodbye world!"
}

// Does contain one of `property1`, `property2`, or `property3`.
{
    property2: "hello again!",
    property4: false
}


Conclusion
This behavior could be achieved if, instead of extending MyInterface, I do something like this:
interface NewInterface
{
    myInterface: CustomRequired<MyInterface>
    property4?: boolean
}

Now, at least one property of MyInterface must be provided to the myInterface property of NewInterface, but it's clunky and I would rather go with the extend method if possible.
The way I imagine it might work is that apart from passing the interface to the utility type CustomRequired, I also pass in a union of property names that do not satisfy the "at least one" requirement. Somewhat similar to the way Omit and Exclude work.
For example:
interface MyInterface
{
    property1?: string
    property2?: string
    proeprty3?: string
}

interface NewInterface extends MyInterface
{
    property4?: boolean
}

// At least one property of `NewInterface` is required, and any property will satisfy it.
// This is the current implementation.
CustomRequired<NewInterface>

// At least one property of `NewInterface` is required, but `property4` won't satisfy it.
CustomRequired<NewInterface, 'property4'>

// At least one property of `NewInterface` is required, but neither `property1` nor `property4` will satisfy it.
CustomRequired<NewInterface, 'property1' | 'property4'>

It would be great if the utility type could handle situations like the one above where no union of keys is passed, as well as situations where a union is passed. If this isn't possible, then it would be okay to have a separate utility type that would only be used when a union needs to be passed, and in other situations where any property will satisfy the requirement I would use my existing utility type.
I'm not well versed enough in TypeScript generics to figure out right away how to do this. I think it would involve passing a second generic representing the union to both CustomRequired and AtLeastOnePropRequired, then make an adjustment to the portions that are referencing keyof T to make sure it isn't also part of the union generic.

If you want to pass the object to a function, maybe you can use the solutions I wrote here: https://shorturl.at/fguwC I've got the idea from type-fest which is a type utility library (https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest)

@ArashJahanBakhshan Thanks, that library looks interesting, I'll look into it for sure. This really would have to be a utility type though similar to CustomRequired.

I think you could write your CustomRequired desired utility type like this:
type CustomRequired<T, K extends keyof T = never> = 
    T & AtLeastOnePropRequired<Omit<T, K>>

where you just Omit the keys from K before passing it to AtLeastOnePropRequired.  Note that if you leave out K, as in CustomRequired<T>, the default value of never is used, and since Omit<T, never> is essentially just T, it falls back to your original version of CustomRequired`.
Let's test it:
type MyType = CustomRequired<NewInterface, "property4">
let t: MyType;

// these are all accepted
t = { property1: "", property2: "", property3: "", property4: true };
t = { property1: "", property4: true };
t = { property2: "", property4: true };
t = { property3: "", property4: true };
t = { property1: "" };

// these are errors
t = {}; // error
t = { property4: true }; // error

Looks good. You must have at least one of the properties of NewInterface, except that property4 doesn't count.
Playground link to code
